# How to determine current active language in qtranslate plugin?

Tags: multi-language, plugin-qtranslate

I have a situation where I want to give specific style to my Navigation Menu when the website is in German language.

My website works well in English language but when I switch to German, it causes a css problem.

So how do I determine which language is currently active with qTranslate plugin?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `qtrans_getLanguage()` function.

```
$currentLang = qtrans_getLanguage();
```

return the current language. See [this link](http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2012/04/03/wordpress-qtranslate-getting-current-language/) for an example

Comment: Unfortunately, both links are not working, official docs is redirected to WordPress forum.

Comment: Thnak's. I've removed the broken link.

Comment: Notice that qtranxf_getLanguage should be used instead for qTranslate X. There is also some compatibility functions in the plugin options according to [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/undefined-function-qtrans_getlanguage)

Answer (score 5):

I have found a possible solution:

```
if ( 'de' === $GLOBALS['q_config']['language'])
{
    echo "<style>#nav li a { margin-left:3px !important; }</style>"; // menu bar width fix
}
```

This works well for my menu items being not looking wired.

Comment: Thanks Kaiser. Does this method work for all global variables?